# Redirect custom page to a product tag

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

Is there a way to redirect a page to a product tag? Before this, I did it with a product category and it worked. So I changed the code to redirect it with a product tag but it didn't work

```
function so_38101217_template_redirect(){
    if( function_exists( 'is_product_tag' ) && is_product_tag( 'raya-2020' ) ){
        $redirect_page_id = 9905; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added the hook for calling this function?

Comment: No. Because when i did for product category, I didnt used any hook. I assumed it would be the same but it isnt

Comment: add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_38101217_template_redirect' ); - add this line in your functions.php in active theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function so_38101217_template_redirect() {
    if ( function_exists( 'is_product_tag' ) && is_product_tag( 'raya-2020' ) ) {
        $redirect_page_id = 9905; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_38101217_template_redirect' );
```

Try this code - add this line in your functions.php in the active theme